# Accept only numbers on a python string

Tags: python

The code does accept numbers but when entered wrong twice it comes up with an error

```
isbn= input('Please enter the 10 digit number: ')
while not(len(isbn) == 10 and isbn.isdigit()):
       print('Please make sure you have entered a number which is exactly 10 characters long.')
       isbn=int(input('Please enter the 10 digit number: '))
       continue

else:
    total= 0
    for i in range(len(isbn)):
           total= int(isbn[i])
    calculation=total%11
    digit11=11-calculation
    if digit11==10:
         digit11='X'
iSBNNumber=str(isbn)+str(digit11)
print('Your 11 digit ISBN Number is ' + iSBNNumber)
```

Comment: Btw, the `else:` after the `while` is not needed. You could take all that code and put indent it one block to the left. Also, I don't think you're doing the right thing with `total = int(isbn[i])`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string` has an `isdigit` method:

```
>>> "1231asd".isdigit()
False
>>> "123131241".isdigit()
True
```

Returns `True` only if all the characters in the string are digits.

So, your condition could be: `not (len(isbn) == 10 and isbn.isdigit())`

Edit: answering your new question (**PLEASE**, don't modify questions like that...)

Don't use `input` here, but `raw_input`. `input` will turn the number into an integer straight away. You want to keep the string, as you are going to operate on individual digits.

```
isbn= raw_input('Please enter the 10 digit number: ')
while not(len(isbn) == 10 and isbn.isdigit()):
       print('Please make sure you have entered a number which is exactly 10 characters long.')
       isbn=raw_input('Please enter the 10 digit number: ')
```

Also, you don't need the `continue`; you only need to use `continue` if you want to skip part of a `while`/`for` loop.

Comment: how can I add that in my code and where

Comment: Errr... the condition I suggested is for your `while` (I thought it was obvious enough)

Comment: Note that this is strictly for digits; if you want to confirm that the user has entered, say, a valid integer, you'll need to handle inputs like `-10`. For ISBNs, pure digits should do.

Comment: @user2357112 as I said "only if all the characters in the string are digits. OP wants to get an ISBN number, which consists only of digits, so...

Comment: so i will replace the while loop with

Comment: not (len(isbn) == 10 and isbn.isdigit())

Comment: With `while not(len(isbn) == 10 and isbn.isdigit()):` Yes... That will give the behaviour you are looking for

Comment: your code perfectly but if i type the code wrong twice it comes up wilth an error can you help me fix that

Comment: Glad to, but I suggest you accept the answer that solved the problem you were asking for, and then post a new question explaining your new problem (that's how this site is supposed to work). You could edit the text on this question adding a link to the new one to draw attention from the people helping you here

Comment: yes thanks can you please vote me up

Comment: i would have voted you up but I dont have enough reputation

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here:

1. checking that the input string is 10 character long and that it contains only numbers:

   ```
   isbn = raw_input("Enter ISBN:")
   if isbn.isdigit() and len(isbn) == 10:
       # go on...
   ```
2. using a regex to validate the input. This approach is much more flexible, but will cost you a little extra effort in understanding regex syntax:

   ```
   import re

   isbncheck = re.compile(r"^\d{10}$")

   isbn = raw_input("Enter ISBN:")
   if isbncheck.match(isbn):
       # go on...
   ```

Here `"^\d{10}$"` means: *"a string composed only and exactly by 10 digits (shortcut for a digit: `\d`)"*.

Comment: isbn= raw_input('Please enter the 10 digit number: ')

if isbn.isdigit() and len(isbn)==10:
    print('Please make sure you have entered a number which is exactly 10 characters long.')
    isbn=int(input('Please enter the 10 digit number: '))
continue

else:
    total= 0
    for i in range(len(isbn)):
        total= int(isbn[i])
    calculation=total%11
    digit11=11-calculation
    if digit11==10:
       digit11='X'
    iSBNNumber=str(isbn)+str(digit11)
    print('Your 11 digit ISBN Number is ' + iSBNNumber)

Comment: No, you have to swap the "then" and the "else" blocks. Also, the `continue` in the then block is pointless.

Comment: can you please add that to my code because each time i do it comes up with an error

Comment: it doesn't matter ive done it but thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be the simplest solution:

```
def MyFunc():
    isbn=raw_input('Please enter the 10 digit number: ')

    try:
        int(isbn)  # we try to get an int from the input... 

    except:
        print "Try again please."  # ... if we fail - ask user to start all over again
        MyFunc()

    """

    Your code goes here

    """

    return ISBN_number

MyFunc()
```

Comment: Maybe the try/except should only *enclose* the int conversion and only except a ValueError. The function should return something in case it is needed later.

Comment: Yeah, this would be better.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to this question.It might have a few indentation errors but im sure you can sort it out after all it doesnt require much coding skills. I have just started this website today and hoping the user an vote this answer up thanks
****************************CODING********************************************************

```
isbn= input('Please enter the 10 digit number: ')
while not(len(isbn) == 10 and isbn.isdigit()):
       print('Please make sure you have entered a number which is exactly 10 characters long.')
       isbn=input('Please enter the 10 digit number: ')


else:
     total= 0
     for i in range(len(isbn)):
         total= int(isbn[i])
         calculation=total%11
         digit11=11-calculation
         if digit11==10:
              digit11='X'
iSBNNumber=str(isbn)+str(digit11)
print('Your 11 digit ISBN Number is ' + iSBNNumber)
```